# Sockets: result too large in listen()-function

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, listen

the other "result too large"-question for c++ sockets didn't help that much. I have a server code, but every time i run it, i get a "result too large"-error for the listen()-function. Hope, you can help!

```
SOCKET sd;
SOCKET sd2;

char serve_1_clien_0_intern;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in client;

void udp_init(unsigned short port_number, int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, char serve_1_clien_0 ){

    WSADATA w;                          
    serve_1_clien_0_intern = serve_1_clien_0;



    if (WSAStartup(0x0101, &w) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open Windows connection.\n");
        return;
        exit(0);
    }


    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create socket.\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return;
        exit(0);
    }

    memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));


    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port_number);
    {
        server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = (unsigned char)a1;
        server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = (unsigned char)a2;
        server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = (unsigned char)a3;
        server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = (unsigned char)a4;
    }


    if(serve_1_clien_0_intern==1){

        if (bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind name to socket, Maybe wrong IP-ADRESS??\n");
            closesocket(sd);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
            exit(0);
        }


        if(listen(sd,10) == SOCKET_ERROR){
            perror("listen");
            exit(0);
        }

        int sin_size;
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if ((sd2 = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client,&sin_size)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
            perror("accept");
            exit(0);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Every example of calling `listen()` I've ever seen used 5 or smaller. I never looked into why that might be, but in your case, do you plan to have more than 5 clients that have called `connect()` to reach your server before your server will call `accept()` on them?

Comment: No, i only want one client to be connected to the server. I just took the 10 from server examples.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you want connected sockets with UDP? It's very unusual. Normally you just use `bind` to bind the socket to a local address and port, and use `recvfrom` on the socket directly.

Comment: You can't listen() or accept() on a UDP socket. Your code is nonsense.

Comment: Yes, I want an UDP Socket. So i just use bind(), recvfrom() and sendto() on the server and on the client side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you use *the wrong function* to print the error. On Windows the socket functions doesn't set `errno`, so the `perror` function can't be used.

Instead you have to use [`WSAGetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the error code. That is why your error message doesn't really make any sense.

---

You should probably use `WSAGetLastError` in the other cases to. For example, `bind` can fail because of other reasons too.

Comment: I get the Error Code 10045: Operation not supported. I don't really know, what I should do with it.

Comment: @user2323546 It seems that Windows enforces the unconnectedness of UDP sockets. You simply can't use UDP socket is passive (listening) mode. See my comment to your question on how it's usually done.